# Linear Optimisation with constraint dependent objective function

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to solve a linear optimisation minimization problem with constraints
$$(a_1\times b_1 \times x_1) + (c_1\times d_1\times x_2) \ +\ . \ . \ . \geq A$$
$$(a_2\times b_2 \times x_1) + (c_2\times d_2\times x_2) \ +\ . \ .\ . \geq B$$
$$...$$$$...$$
where $x_i$ are integers bounded between $0$ and $n$, and $a_i$, $b_i$... are constants, for the objective function
$$ (\alpha_1\times x_1) + (\alpha_2\times x_2)... $$
where the value of $\alpha_i$ is dependent on the value of $x_i$.

I am using [pulp](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/) to solve a version of this problem where I feed in the values of $x_i$ [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdzYF.png), and $\alpha_i$ as a list of values. However I'd like a way to set $\alpha_i$ equal to some value depending on the value of $x_i$, so that the final output of the optimization $x_i$  reflects the variation. Put simply, the more of each $x_i$ the algorithm uses, the higher $\alpha_i$ will be, in this case in a stepwise nature.

My question is - is this possible? Can I use pulp? How can I do it?

Comment: So the objective function is of the form $f(x_1) \cdot x$?

Comment: @Joppy Yes, that is a more succinct way to put it, but it would be $f(x_i).x_i$. I edited the mistake in the post